# Proper use of ◎ことは◎ for する verbs

Tags: grammar

There is a grammar rule in DoBJG which looks like ◎ことは◎, where both ◎ are the same verbs (or adjectives). But there is no examples with する-verbs in this book.

Which one is correct?

- 私は日本語を勉強することは勉強しましたが不合格でした。
- 私は日本語を勉強することはしましたが不合格でした。

If none, how should I construct a sentence using said grammar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are grammatical and perfectly make sense, but the former looks a bit too wordy to me. Anyway, this is a rather literary construction, and probably 勉強するにはしたが or 勉強しはしたが is more common, according to some quick searches on [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/).